# Why Sift Feature Detector cannot detect key points for some images?

Tags: c++, opencv, feature-detection, sift, keypoint

I am reading images from a set and extracting their features. However, for some images(very few, around 4 per mille), `SiftFeatureDetector::detect( image, keypoints)` cannot detect key points and returns me an empty set of key points. When I tried with `SurfFeatureDetector::detect( image, keypoints)`, it detects the key points.

Here is the code:

```
    query = imread( it->path().string());

    /* Here, I resize the image in proportion so that its longest side will be 400*/

    cvtColor( query, query_gray, CV_RGB2GRAY);

    SiftFeatureDetector feature_detector;
    vector<KeyPoint> query_kp;
    feature_detector.detect( query_gray, query_kp);

    // check whether KeyPoints are detected
    if( !query_kp.size())
    {
        cerr << "KeyPoints couldn't be detected. Image " << it->path() << " is skipped." << endl;
        ++cantDetecteds;
        waitKey(0);
        continue;
    }
```

What is the reason behind this? Can someone explain please?

Thanks.

**EDIT:** Surf also cannot detect some key points , around 2 per mille.

Comment: can you post sample images? Probably there just aren't any Sift featurs in those images for the given parameter set...

Comment: http://3.1m.yt/9Ny27Vp.jpg                                               http://3.1m.yt/EBOIV_6.jpg                                                                           http://3.1m.yt/eW-N7-A.jpg                                                         http://3.1m.yt/T-l2LfD.jpg                                           http://3.1m.yt/5RUfSNd.jpg                                            http://3.1m.yt/TLi3teE.jpg                                         http://3.1m.yt/W23WF1J.jpg

Comment: from intuition I would say that the first two images should give sift features. Probably the contrast isn't high enough, can you try to decrease the threshold used in sift and/or normalize (e.g. histogram equalization on the grayscale image) the image before computing sift? Typically it gives better comparable results if images are normalized and it might be much esier to find a threshold. Another approach could be to fix the wanted number of features and vary the threshold until you find anough features.

Comment: @Micka You are probably right. I tried SURF with hessian threshold = 50 and it detects key points from all images. Normalization would also work in that case but I did not try. Thanks!